# Does FT232RLMG support RS-485?

Tags: usb, rs485, ftdi, modbus

I have the *FT232RLMG* device and a device that uses the RS-485 connection standard.
I would like to know if I can connect the TX and RX pins of the FT232RLMG to the device that uses RS-485 *directly* or do I *need some more components*?

I have looked for information in the datasheet and found that it specifies in the section typical applications:

- USB to RS232 / RS422 / RS485 Converters

In the and in technical characteristics says:

- Data transfer rates from 300 baud to 3 Mbaud (RS422, RS485, RS232) at
  TTL levels.

Link to datasheet: [FT232R](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf)

Thank you very much.

Comment: No, you cannot connect it directly to either RS-232 or RS-485.  In either case an appropriate inverting level shifter and possibly differential converter is required to go from the IC's logic level to the interface signalling standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RS-485](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485) uses differential signaling

[RS-232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) uses single ended signaling

They are not directly hardware compatible.

There are many off the shelf hardware devices that convert from RS-232 to RS-485. I believe single IC components exist as well although the ones I've worked with are RS-232 at 5V and 3.3V logic levels (UART) not full RS-232 voltage levels.

Comment: This mostly misses the point - the FT232 ICs support *neither* RS-232 nor RS-485, a product based on one which supports those must include a line driver and receiver from the USB IC's logic level to the interface standard level and polarity.